# Inspect Element on Android to view values of cookies without the need of root

Tags: android, cookies, browser, web-inspector

```
javascript:(function () { 
    var script =  document.createElement('script');
    script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; 
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = function () { 
        eruda.init() 
    } 
})();
```

This script can do something like **`Inspect Element`** using **`Chrome in Android`**. You just need to add a bookmark which has a url that contains this script. I've tried using it with other websites like the results when I searched from google, websites from the results given by google, and even this website Stackoverflow. They are all https but this script still can do its job, but there's this Facebook which this script doesn't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use eruda's Inspect inject code. Or Use [Kiwi browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser).

> They are all https but this script still can do its job, but there's this Facebook which this script doesn't work. Why is that?

The provided JavaScript bookmarklet injects the Eruda library to enable debugging tools on webpages. However, it doesn't work on Facebook, likely due to the site's strict Content Security Policy, anti-tampering measures, user-agent detection, and potential anti-debugging techniques. While it functions on less security-conscious websites, Facebook's robust security measures present a challenge for external scripts like Eruda to operate effectively.

Answer (score -2):

javascript:(function () {
var script = document.creatElement('script');

script.src="//cdn.jsdlivr.net/npm/eruda";

document.body.appendChild(script);

script.onload = function () {
eruda.init()

}
})();

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

javascript:(function () { %C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0 var script =%C2%A0 document.createElement('script'); %C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0 script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; %C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0 document.body.appendChild(script); %C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0 script.onload = function () { %C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0 eruda.init() %C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0 } })();

Comment: I think that is broken syntax. You probably need this info to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.